# python pandas passing 3 columns pairs of data into a loop and MySQL queries

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, indexing

Assume we have a csv

```
PROPERTY_ID,CLIENT_ID,FROM_YEAR
1,5,2015
2,6,2015
3,9,2015
4,9,2015
```

I am trying to pass each unique combination of CLIENT_ID, PROPERTY_ID,FROM_YEAR into a dictionary, so I can put the "PROPERTY_ID,CLIENT_ID,FROM_YEAR" pair into MySQL queries:

```
for i in CLIENT_ID

  do 

   connect to MySQL

   SELECT * FROM DATABASE_${CLIENT_ID}.TABLE WHERE PROPERTY IN ${PROPERTY_ID} AND FROM_YEAR = ${FROM_YEAR};

   disconnect to MySQL

 done
```

In a real number way, not parameters:

```
for i in CLIENT_ID

  do 

   connect to MySQL

   SELECT * FROM DATABASE_9.TABLE WHERE PROPERTY IN ('3','4') AND FROM_YEAR = 2015;

   disconnect to MySQL

 done
```

Now the solution I can think of is to transform the python panda frame into dictionary:

```
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df2=df.T.to_dict('list')
```

But it will return a dictionary of an interesting key:values pairs:

indexing: (CLIENT_ID,PROPERTY_ID,FROM_YEAR)

```
{0: [5, 1,2015], 1: [6, 2,2015], 2: [9, 3,2015], 3: [9, 4,2015]}
```

Any simpler solution to proceed?

## <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Hi @piRSquared,

Thanks for your answer. Is there any way that we can make the following?

```
1st round:
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=5,1,2015

2nd round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=6,2,2015

3rd round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,3,2015

4th round
$CLIENT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,$FROM_YEAR=9,4,2015
```

so that we can print out SQL queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM client_5 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 1 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;

SELECT * FROM client_6 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 2 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;

SELECT * FROM client_9 WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 3 and FROM_YEAR = 2015;
```

I have tried to use list comprehension:

```
for CLIENT_ID in [x[0] for x in df2]:

    CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID.astype('str')

    print "SELECT * FROM client"+CLIENT_ID
    
    for PROPERTY_CODE in [y[1] for y in df2]:

        PROPERTY_CODE=PROPERTY_CODE.astype('str')

        print "WHERE PROPERTY_ID = "+PROPERTY_CODE
```

it returns the following, which is not we are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM client_5
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 1
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 2
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 3
WHERE FK_PROPERTY_ID = 4
```

Could you enlighten? Thanks.

Comment: Terribly slow to have connect/disconnect inside the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***setup***

```
txt = """PROPERTY_ID,CLIENT_ID,FROM_YEAR
1,5,2015
2,6,2015
3,9,2015
4,9,2015
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))
```

***option 1***
`apply` + `tuple` + `unique`

```
df.apply(tuple, 1).unique().tolist()

[(1, 5, 2015), (2, 6, 2015), (3, 9, 2015), (4, 9, 2015)]
```

***option 2***
list comprehension + `drop_duplicates`

```
[tuple(x) for x in df.drop_duplicates().values]

[(1, 5, 2015), (2, 6, 2015), (3, 9, 2015), (4, 9, 2015)]
```

Comment: hi piRSquared, Thanks for your kind answer.  Learning a trick!  I have responded above.  Could you help? Thanks!